# How to update a view in react when data changes

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, express, rxjs

I'm trying to learn about a lot of stuff like: Typescript, Express and my new "obsessions" REACT and RXJS.

I created a [Quick-List on github](https://github.com/PedroDrim/Quick-List) to study these things, but I found a question...

"How to update a view in react when data changes"

I have an object "List" on the class "IndexRoute":

```
import { NextFunction, Request, Response, Router } from "express";
import { List } from "../model/list";
import { Person } from "../model/person";
import * as _ from "lodash";

/**
 * Classe responsável por gerenciar as rotas de Index.
 */
export class IndexRoute {

  private router: Router;
  private list: List; <----[HERE]----

  /**
   * Constructor
   *
   * @class IndexRoute
   * @constructor
   */
  constructor(router: Router) {

    this.router = router;
    this.createList();
    this.routesForGET();
    this.routesForPOST();
    this.routesForPUT();
    this.routesForDELETE();
  }

  private createList() {
    this.list = new List();
    this.list.addPerson(new Person("111", "Joao", 1));
    this.list.addPerson(new Person("1325", "Maria", 10));
    this.list.addPerson(new Person("1564", "José", 25));
  }

  private routesForGET() {

    //Get Rota padrão (index)
    this.router.get("/", (req: Request, res: Response) => {

      var person: Person = this.list.getPersonByCPF("111");

      //set options
      let options: Object = {
        "title": "Express",
        "name": JSON.stringify(this.list.getList())
      };

      var view: string = "index";
      res.render(view, options);
    });
  }

  private routesForPOST() {

    //Adicionar uma nova person via REST
    this.router.post("/", (req: Request, res: Response) => {

      if (_.isEmpty(req.body)) {
        res.status(400).send("Não foi possivel adicionar o elemento, verifique os parametros.");
      } else {

        var cpf: string = req.params.cpf;

        var person = new Person(
          req.body.cpf,
          req.body.name,
          req.body.age
        );

        this.list.addPerson(person);
        res.send("Elemento adicionado com sucesso.");
      }
    });

    //Visualizar uma person com base no cpf
    this.router.post("/:cpf", (req: Request, res: Response) => {

      var cpf: string = req.params.cpf;
      var person: Person = this.list.getPersonByCPF(cpf);

      if (_.isEmpty(person)) {
        res.status(400).send("Não foi possivel encontrar o elemento.");
      } else {
        res.json(person);
      }

    });

    //Exibir body
    this.router.post("/get/list", (req: Request, res: Response) => {

      var l: Person[] = this.list.getList();
      if(_.isEmpty(l)){
        res.status(400).send("Lista vazia.");
      }else{
        res.json(l);
      }

    });

    //Exibir body
    this.router.post("/get/body", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
      res.send(JSON.stringify(req.body));
    });
  }

  private routesForPUT() {

    //Atualizar uma person com base no cpf
    this.router.put("/:cpf", (req: Request, res: Response) => {

      if (_.isEmpty(req.body)) {
        res.status(400).send("Não foi possivel adicionar o elemento, verifique os parametros.");
      } else {

        var cpf: string = req.params.cpf;

        var person = new Person(
          req.body.cpf,
          req.body.name,
          req.body.age
        );

        if (this.list.updatePersonByCPF(cpf, person)) {
          res.send("Elemento atualizado com sucesso.");
        } else {
          res.status(400).send("Não foi possivel atualizar o elemento,     verifique os parametros.");
        }

      }

    });
  }

  private routesForDELETE() {

    //Remover uma person com base no cpf
    this.router.delete("/:cpf", (req: Request, res: Response) => {

      var cpf: string = req.params.cpf;

      if (this.list.removePersonByCPF(cpf)) {
        res.send("Elemento removido com sucesso.");
      } else {
        res.status(400).send("Não foi possivel remover o elemento, verifique os parametros.");
      }

    });
  }
}
```

And I have the REACT component:

```
var React = require('react');
var DefaultLayout = require('./layouts/default');

class HelloMessage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <DefaultLayout title={this.props.title}>
        <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>
      </DefaultLayout>
    );
  }
}

module.exports = HelloMessage;
```

My objective is: When the list in "IndexRoute" class changes, the view changes too.

OBS.: **Without use angular**.

But there is my main problem... I don't have any idea about how to do it, idk if reactive programming is the best idea, idk if i have to use react-native, exist a lot of tools to be used but idk what is the best for this scenario.

I know that angular can solve it but i like to learn another way.

Comment: You need to pass a different `props` to `HelloMessage` each time list changes, in order to re-render

Comment: i'm thinking to get the data as a state with fetch to update with setState, I think it's more easy to do.

Comment: What does OBS mean? If it means obviously, it should be spelled out instead of being abbreviated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I studied more and know how to solve it:

1 - Stopping to use [express-react-views](https://github.com/reactjs/express-react-views), it doesn't support mount views on the client.

2 - I have a route that return the list elements, I'll catch them with **fetch()** and update the view with **setState()**.

Thx for all, and if someone saw anything wrong in my solution, please tell me to improve more. :)

Answer (score 0):

> When the list in "IndexRoute" class changes, the view changes too.

The `props` used by the component (passed in from its parent) need to change based on route change.

## More

> I don't have any idea about how to do it, idk if reactive programming is the best idea

Walk before running. Start with hello world https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html

Comment: I did it before to post, but was nice to remember the lifecycle again, thx. Now about the solution I'm thinking to use fetch to receive the list, insert as a state and verify / update with setInterval. But now there is another problem...setState() don't update the value.